# Elixir Kernel.apply/2 and Kernel.apply/3 alternatives?

Tags: elixir, apply, args

I'm creating a task that executes a function dynamically. This function is different each time, and so are the number of arguments (`[1, "hi", :a]`), so I was using `Kernel.apply/2`.

```ex
defp create_task(f, args) do
    Task.async(fn -> apply(f, args) end)
end
```

But I'm unable to get this to work with private functions (declared using `defp`):

```ex
create_task(&__MODULE__.my_private_fun/3, args)
```

Comment: How are you currently calling this function? If the function you're passing is defined using `defp` in a module, then there is no way you can call it from outside.

Comment: Though, this smells more like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am calling it from the same module @Sheharyar

Comment: Then it should work without any issues. Just pass it like `create_task(&my_private_fun/3, args)` (there's no getting around the arity part).

Comment: I was passing them as create_task(&__MODULE__.my_private_fun/3, args) ...

Do you want to make a reply to the question so I can rate you?

Comment: I read the questions, the answer and every comment... and I do not get what you were or are looking for @deko

Comment: Hi Nathan. What happened was I thought one couldn't use Kernel.apply/2 with private functions in the same module. This is because I was passing my functions like "&__MODULE__.my_private_fun/3", this is, including the module name before the function name and arity. Now, I pass them as "&my_private_fun/3", and Kernel.apply/2 does not complain about those functions being private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function you're passing is defined using `defp` in a module, then there is no way you can call it from outside. But you can still call it if it's in the same module:

```
create_task(&my_private_fun/3, args)
```

The important thing to note here is that there is no getting around the fact that you have to specify the function arity (without macros), so why not just call the function directly?

Comment: I'm afraid I might not understand what you are saying in your last paragraph, probably due do my lack of understanding of the English language.

In case you want to see my whole "exercise":
https://github.com/dsuarezgarcia/AS/blob/master/exercicios/e10_tarefas/lib/measure.ex

I was using Kernel.apply/3 originally.

Comment: [Arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) is the `/3` part at the end which means the number of arguments a function accepts.